# Formula to calculate square positioning

Tags: user-interface, math, language-agnostic

I'm trying to arrange the squares as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlfBh.png) . Each square is smaller than the previous one by a constant value. When positioning a square, I know:

1. Its size
2. The size of the large square (square in the centre)
3. Index relative to the centre, i.e., ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2...
4. Actual index, i.e., 0,1,2,3,4...
5. Indent constant (the value by which the current square is less than the previous one)

The formula must necessarily contain multiplication by the index relative to the centre because the squares can change their position by multiplication on it.

I'm writing some code for it, but it's not ideal. Constant (0.5) is an eyeballed value.

```
Float GetCardPosition(Int Index) {
    var Distance = CenterIndex - Index; // index relative to the center
    var Size = GetCardSize(index);
    var CardCenter = Size / 2;
    var Center = MaxWidth / 2;
    var CenterIndent = Indent / 2;
    var CardPos = Center - CardCenter;
    var Pos = (CardCenter + CenterIndent * Math.abs(Distance) * 0.5) * Distance;

    return CardPos - Pos;
  }
```

Comment: If S_i is the length of the side of the ith square (for i >= 0) then S_{i+1} = S_i - c where c is some positive constant. Then you know the (i+1)th square must have a centre that is S_i/2 to the right of the centre of the ith square. You can just mirror the results for the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple observation will help you. The center of the squares starting with square number zero is 0, 7, 12, 15, 16 (and negative in the opposite direction). This is 16 - 16, 16 - 9, 16 - 4, 16 - 1, 16 - 0. So the simple formula for the n-th square center is f(n) = 16 - (4 - n)^2.

Comment: This is a good formula and explanation. For a more general approach, to get number 4 in the formula, should I use a square root of 16 (half of the summary width)?

Comment: Yes. Also, 4 here is the number of squares right (or left) of the center square including the center square. If you want to know the center of the n-th square of an arrangement with 1 Square in the middle and m-1 squares to each side, it is f_m(n) = m^2 - (m - n)^2. The sidelength of such a square should be 4m - 2 - 4n.